# Adobe Illustrator can't change color profile

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The colours in Adobe Illustrator have suddenly turned horrible, blue looks purple. I've been trying to search for help on the topic but everyone is able to click "Edit > Assign Profile" and change the settings in "Color Settings" but I can't.

I tried looking for someone else's Color Settings File (.csf) but couldn't find one to use. I'm not able to use Illustrator for design work and I don't know why forcing Emulating Adobe Illustrator 6.0 is even the default and locking me into it.

I haven't been able to figure it out through existing resources.

[image][image]

Comment: You're going to need to contact Adobe for this one. We don't do tech support on here, sorry.

Comment: So.. you're saying in the first screenshot above.. you *can't* change it to anything *other* than "custom"? --- trash prefs, relaunch app.